# Try to build own Angular table components but false HTML structure

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html-table

I try to write my own Angular table components (table-container, table-row and table-item)

This should look like this

```
<app-table-container>
  <app-table-row>
    <app-table-item></app-table-item>
    <app-table-item></app-table-item>
    <app-table-item></app-table-item>
  </app-table-row>
</app-table-container>
```

table-container.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-container',
  templateUrl: './table-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-container.component.scss']
})
export class TableContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

table-container.component.html

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

table-row.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-row',
  templateUrl: './table-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-row.component.scss']
})
export class TableRowComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

table-row.component.html

```
<tr>
  <td>Cell 1.1</td>
  <td>Cell 1.2</td>
  <td>Cell 1.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cell 2.1</td>
  <td>Cell 2.2</td>
  <td>Cell 2.3</td>
</tr>
```

and the app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'testing-project';
  public tableListObjects: any[] = [
    {
      name: {
        forename: 'Jens',
        surname: 'Vial'
      },
      age: 32,
      job: 'Software Engineer',
      vacation: false
    },
    {
      name: {
        forename: 'Hans',
        surname: 'Peter'
      },
      age: 22,
      job: 'Electrican',
      vacation: true
    }];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

and the app.component.html

```
<app-table-container>
  <app-table-row></app-table-row>
</app-table-container>
```

for now, without the app-table-item component because the problem is in the app-table-row-component.
The problem is, that the table-structure is false.
I expect a table with 3 columns header 1 - 3 and two rows with cell 1.1 - 1.3 and 2.1 - 2.3
Instead the cells 1.1 - 1.3 and 2.1 - 2.3 are in the first column from header 1 see the image.

[image]

I have absolutely no idea why this happens. Can anyone tell me, at which point I make a mistake?

The DOM looks like this

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the elements that end up in the DOM?

Comment: I update my post and insert a image from the DOM. I think the DOM is correct

Comment: It's not correct. You can see the app-table-row element? You need the tr to be *direct* children of the tbody.

Comment: In the resulting HTML, the tbody is embedded in an app-table-row element. This causes the tbody to think it's the only element in its parent, ignoring the thead.

Comment: Ahh thanks, ok now I see the wrong DOM. Is there a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is you're looking for, but if you don't want to create addicional tags, you can use the way

```
<tr app-table-row></tr>
```

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkaaxn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) has an example, but the app becomes like

```
<app-table-container>
  <tr app-table-row>
    <td app-table-cell>cell 1</td>
    <td app-table-cell>cell 1</td>
    <td app-table-cell>cell 1</td>
  </tr>
</app-table-container>
```

the templates of app-table-row and app-table-cell are simple

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Comment: thanks for this solution, but unfortunately it's not that what i need. I really need 3 independent componants (with ts and html) to puzzle a table